# Change column values when specific condition is satisfied

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr

I have the problem following on which I'm thinking for a while and cannot figure out the solution.

Let's consider some artificial data frame and it's 0.9 and 0.1 quantiles:

```
set.seed(42)
x = data.frame("Norm" = rnorm(100),
               "Unif" = runif(100),
               "Exp" = rexp(100))

quants_b <- apply(x, 2, quantile, 0.90)
quants_s <- apply(x, 2, quantile, 0.10)
```

What I want to do in this data frame is to check which values are bigger than its corresponding quantile 0.9 and less than corresponding quantile 0.1 and changed all those values to the limits.

In simpler words:

I want to check which values exceed 0.9 quantile and all those values transform to 0.9 quantile

and I want to do the same with 0.1 quantile.

**Troublesomeness of the problem**

This problem in my opinion looks very easy at the first sight, however it has one trap - we have to do the transformation in the same time, because if we firstly change the upper bound and then lower, between the transformation quantiles can change.

(Please notice that we want to replace first variable with element of `quants_s` and `quants_b`, second with second and so on).

**My ideas**

My first idea was to use `dplyr` package and a function `mutate_all` within it.

```
x %>% dplyr::mutate_all(
  function(x) {
    ifelse(sweep(x, 2,STATS=quants_s, `<`), quants_s,
           ifelse(sweep(x, 2,STATS=quants_b, `>`), 
                 quants_b, x)
    )
  }
)
```

This code intuitively is very simple - we just change all values which are lower than `quants_s` with `quants_s`, and those which are bigger than `quants_b` with `quants_b`. Remaining data stays the same.
However I got error following and I'm not sure how to omit it:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Norm`.
x 'dims' cannot be of length 0
i Input `Norm` is `(function (x) ...`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Could you please give me a hand solving the problem/pointing another solution ?

Comment: I don't understand the problem with simultaneous change. For instance, if a number is below the 0.1-ile, then regardless of what we do with another value (that may or may not be above the 0.9-ile), when that second operation is done, this one number is *still* below the 0.1-ile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(. > quantile(., 0.9), quantile(., 0.9),
                                 ifelse(
                                     . < quantile(., 0.1), quantile(., 0.1),
                                      .))))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this should be easily resolved with `pmin` and `pmax` in a "clamping" method.

Start by pre-calculating the limits:

```r
quants <- apply(x, 2, quantile, c(0.1, 0.9))
quants
#          Norm       Unif       Exp
# 10% -1.211724 0.08499473 0.1257829
# 90%  1.372974 0.88512802 2.5315087
```

Then apply that in one step:

```r
head(x, 15)
#           Norm       Unif       Exp  # outside bounds
# 1   1.37095845 0.88511769 0.7350033
# 2  -0.56469817 0.51711106 0.2718374
# 3   0.36312841 0.85193098 1.6570686
# 4   0.63286260 0.44279627 0.9729376
# 5   0.40426832 0.15788010 0.9210097
# 6  -0.10612452 0.44232464 2.4238688
# 7   1.51152200 0.96773367 2.5686363  # <-- Norm Unif Exp
# 8  -0.09465904 0.48458793 1.5920526
# 9   2.01842371 0.25245844 0.3064365  # <-- Norm
# 10 -0.06271410 0.25968998 0.2982843
# 11  1.30486965 0.54201594 1.2682549
# 12  2.28664539 0.64987584 1.5215655  # <-- Norm
# 13 -1.38886070 0.33641913 0.8123740  # <-- Norm
# 14 -0.27878877 0.06094975 0.1296444  # <--      Unif
# 15 -0.13332134 0.45131085 0.2484241

x[] <- Map(function(x, q1, q9) pmax(q1, pmin(q9, x)), x, quants[1,], quants[2,])
head(x, 15)
#           Norm       Unif       Exp
# 1   1.37095845 0.88511769 0.7350033
# 2  -0.56469817 0.51711106 0.2718374
# 3   0.36312841 0.85193098 1.6570686
# 4   0.63286260 0.44279627 0.9729376
# 5   0.40426832 0.15788010 0.9210097
# 6  -0.10612452 0.44232464 2.4238688
# 7   1.37297365 0.88512802 2.5315087  # <-- Norm Unif Exp
# 8  -0.09465904 0.48458793 1.5920526
# 9   1.37297365 0.25245844 0.3064365  # <-- Norm
# 10 -0.06271410 0.25968998 0.2982843
# 11  1.30486965 0.54201594 1.2682549
# 12  1.37297365 0.64987584 1.5215655  # <-- Norm
# 13 -1.21172411 0.33641913 0.8123740  # <-- Norm
# 14 -0.27878877 0.08499473 0.1296444  # <--      Unif
# 15 -0.13332134 0.45131085 0.2484241
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something subtle, but here's a straight forward approach with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~case_when(. > quantile(.,0.9) ~ quantile(.,0.9),
                                         . < quantile(.,0.1) ~ quantile(.,0.1),
                                         TRUE ~ .)))
```

Here we can see the effect:

```
x %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~case_when(. > quantile(.,0.9) ~ "High",
                                         . < quantile(.,0.1) ~ "Low",
                                         TRUE ~ ""),.names = "{.col}Δ")) %>%
  mutate(across(!contains("Δ"),~case_when(. > quantile(.,0.9) ~ quantile(.,0.9),
                                          . < quantile(.,0.1) ~ quantile(.,0.1),
                                          TRUE ~ .))) %>%
  select(sort(tidyselect::peek_vars())) %>%
  head(n=15)
#         Exp ExpΔ        Norm NormΔ       Unif UnifΔ
#1  0.7350033       1.37095845       0.88511769      
#2  0.2718374      -0.56469817       0.51711106      
#3  1.6570686       0.36312841       0.85193098      
#4  0.9729376       0.63286260       0.44279627      
#5  0.9210097       0.40426832       0.15788010      
#6  2.4238688      -0.10612452       0.44232464      
#7  2.5315087 High  1.37297365  High 0.88512802  High
#8  1.5920526      -0.09465904       0.48458793      
#9  0.3064365       1.37297365  High 0.25245844      
#10 0.2982843      -0.06271410       0.25968998      
#11 1.2682549       1.30486965       0.54201594      
#12 1.5215655       1.37297365  High 0.64987584      
#13 0.8123740      -1.21172411   Low 0.33641913      
#14 0.1296444      -0.27878877       0.08499473   Low
#15 0.2484241      -0.13332134       0.45131085
```